# MVC 6 Cookie Authentication - Getting User Details From the Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm working on an MVC 6 application that does **not** use Entity or Identity.  Instead, I'm using Dapper.  I have a controller that accepts a POST request and uses Dapper to check the database to see if the users name / password match.  All I'd like to do is store the users name and whether they're logged in or not so I can make that check on subsequent pages.

I looked around and it seems like using Cookie based authentication should allow me to do what I want.  Here's the relevant code in my `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = "/account/login",
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Here's what the relevant code in my controllers login action looks like:

```
var user = _repo.FindByLogin(model.VendorId, model.Password);
if (user != null) {
 var claims = new List < Claim > {
  new Claim("VendorId", user.VendorId),
  new Claim("Name", "john")
 };

 var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "local", "name", "role");
 await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
 var l = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType;
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "PurchaseOrders");
}
```

The above code *seems* to work in that a cookie is being saved, but I'm not sure how I would go about getting the user information back out of the cookie (or even how to retrieve the cookie on subsequent requests in the first place).

In my mind I'm imagining being able to do something like: `var user = (User)HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(????)`, but I'm not sure if that's practical or not.

Comment: The cookie is in the request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18.aspx. It's okay to use cookie data to prepopulate fields or something, but cookies can be manipulated by the end user, so never blindly trust information in them.

Comment: Gotcha.  Would it be better to save the data in a server side session then?  If so, the same question would apply.  It seems like Microsoft makes it a massive pain to try and use anything other than Identity + EF.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest storing the data in the session on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user data back by using the ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(xxx)

here is my example class which can be used in Controller/Views to get the current user information

```
public class GlobalSettings : IGlobalSettings
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public GlobalSettings(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }    

        public string RefNo
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue(_accessor.HttpContext.User, "employeeid");
            }
        }

        public string SAMAccount
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue(_accessor.HttpContext.User, ClaimTypes.WindowsAccountName);
            }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue(_accessor.HttpContext.User, ClaimTypes.Name);
            }
        }

        public string Role
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue(_accessor.HttpContext.User, ClaimTypes.Role);
            }
        }

        private string GetValue(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string key)
        {
            if (principal == null)
                return string.Empty;

            return principal.FindFirstValue(key);
        }
}
```

Example Usage in controller after DI:

```
var currentUser = GlobalSettings.SAMAccount;
```

Please note that you need to inject HttpContextAccessor in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```